# Ideal error page for Java EE App

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, exception

I'm having a tough time consolidating errors in my application.  Currently, my `error.jsp` looks like following (part of it):

```
 <%@ page isErrorPage="true" %>
 <%@page contentType="text/html"%>
 <%@page import="java.util.*"%>
 <%@page import="javax.servlet.*"%>
 <%@page import="javax.servlet.http.*"%>
 <%@page import="java.util.Calendar"%>
 <%@page import="java.text.SimpleDateFormat"%>

<html>
<%
String code = null, message = null, type = null, uri = null, time = null;
Object codeObj=null, messageObj=null, typeObj=null;
if (request.getAttribute("javax.servlet.error.status_code") != null)
    codeObj = request.getAttribute("javax.servlet.error.status_code");
if (request.getAttribute("javax.servlet.error.message") != null)
    messageObj = request.getAttribute("javax.servlet.error.message");
if (request.getAttribute("javax.servlet.error.exception_type")!=null)
    typeObj = request.getAttribute("javax.servlet.error.exception_type");

if (codeObj != null) code = codeObj.toString();
if (messageObj != null) message = messageObj.toString();
if (typeObj != null) type = typeObj.toString();
uri = (String) request.getAttribute("javax.servlet.error.request_uri");
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss:SSS");
time = sdf.format(cal.getTime());

String error = "Code:\t\t" + code + "\nType:\t\t" + type + "\nURL:\t\t" + uri + "\nTime:\t\t" + time +"\nMessage:\t" + message;
%>
```

This works fine in all scenarios except!:
Sometimes in my application I am catching built-in exceptions in `MyException` class with the following code:

```
catch(MyException ex){
    log.error(ex.getMessage(), uivex);
    String originalURL = "/errorpages/error.jsp?errorcode=" + (ex.getMajor() + ex.getMinor()) + "&errormessage=" + ex.getMessage();
    RequestDispatcher dispatcher = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher(address);
    dispatcher.forward(request,response);   
}
```

Now the problem is that when I get forwarded to `error.jsp` page...Instead of seeing the actual error from `MyException` class..I'm seeing `NullPointerException` because nothing is present in `javax.servlet.error.status_code` and the page is declared as `isErrorPage="true"`

What should I do in this case?  One solution is to make a completely different error.jsp (name it error1.jsp) page and forward the exceptions from `MyException` class to that page.  Though, I would like to have everything in one place.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This code honestly [hurts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/howto-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files) my eyes. Here is how a generic one should look like. You may find it useful.

```
<%@ page pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" prefix="fmt" %>
<jsp:useBean id="date" class="java.util.Date" />
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Error</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Error</h1>
        <p>Unfortunately an unexpected error has occurred. Below you can find the error details.</p>
        <h2>Details</h2>
        <ul>
            <li>Timestamp: <fmt:formatDate value="${date}" type="both" dateStyle="long" timeStyle="long" />
            <li>Action: <c:out value="${requestScope['javax.servlet.forward.request_uri']}" />
            <li>Exception: <c:out value="${requestScope['javax.servlet.error.exception']}" />
            <li>Message: <c:out value="${requestScope['javax.servlet.error.message']}" />
            <li>Status code: <c:out value="${requestScope['javax.servlet.error.status_code']}" />
            <li>User agent: <c:out value="${header['user-agent']}" />
        </ul>
    </body>
</html>
```

The `@page isErrorPage` is by the way only useful if you want to have the `${exception}` (i.e. `request.getAttribute("exception")` available in the JSP. In this particular case you don't need it.

And indeed, do not forward in the `catch` block at all. Just let it go. It will be dealt by the error page then.

```
} catch (MyException ex) {
    log.error(ex.getMessage(), uivex);
    throw ex; // Or throw new ServletException(ex.getMessage(), ex);
}
```

Comment: If I `throw ex` then error stack is written in server.log .  I want it to only be written in `my_system.log` (comes from `log.error`)

Comment: I really don't see how that's a problem. You're already logging it to your own log using `log.error()`. If you want to disable server stderr logging, just configure so in the server config.

Comment: Ideally I would like to do exaclty that! so that Instead of dealing with exceptions I can just log it to my own log and then just throw it out! How would I configure/disabled stderr logging in GlassFish. I can search on google as well but not sure exactly what to look for

Comment: Again, I really don't see how that's a problem. You could just ignore the server's own logfile at its whole own. Anyway, you can configure logging in the admin console.

Comment: @BalusC Thanks for another excellent answer.  This one is good for reference too.

Answer (score 1):

Put all details in the logs and show the user only a vague message that something went wrong, regardless of what the exception is. So your error page may look like (to quote twitter):

```
<%@ page isErrorPage="true" %>

Something went technically wrong.
```

And do not catch & forward - simply let the exception bubble. The other alternative is, as you say, make two separate pages that include the common content, and differ only in the `isErrorPage` definition.

Comment: but the problem will still be there. when a jsp page is decalared is `isErrorPage` the `javax.servlet.error.status_code` must have something in it or else a Null Pointer Exception is thrown.

Comment: I thought in last question you suggested that if I want to avoid putting exceptions in server.log then I need to catch them and that's the only option. that's why I am now catching it and forwarding.

Comment: Yes, given the other question (I didn't relate the two initially) then forwarding sounds less bad.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a custom stackTrace jsp tag  and include it in a special error page:

The tag file (WEB-INF/tags/stackTrace.tag)

```
<%@tag description="Prints stack trace of the specified Throwable"
          pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>

<%-- content (prints stack trace) --%>
<%
      java.io.PrintWriter pOut = new java.io.PrintWriter(out);
      try {
         // The Servlet spec guarantees this attribute will be available
         Throwable err = (Throwable) 
             request.getAttribute("javax.servlet.error.exception");

         if(err != null) {
            if(err instanceof ServletException) {
               // It's a ServletException: we should extract the root cause
               ServletException se = (ServletException) err;
               Throwable rootCause = se.getRootCause();
               if(rootCause == null) {
                  rootCause = se;
               }
               out.println("** Root cause is: " + rootCause.getMessage());
               rootCause.printStackTrace(pOut);
            }else {
               // It's not a ServletException, so we'll just show it
               err.printStackTrace(pOut);
            }
         }else {
            out.println("No error information available");
         }

         // Display cookies
         out.println("\nCookies:\n");
         Cookie[] cookies = request.getCookies();
         if(cookies != null) {
            for(int i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
               out.println(cookies[i].getName() + "=[" + 
                   cookies[i].getValue() + "]");
            }
         }

      }catch(Exception ex) {
         ex.printStackTrace(pOut);
      }
%>
```

The error.jsp could be like so: (Add some humor to it, if you app somewhat casual)

```
<%@ page isErrorPage="true" %>
<html>
   <head>
    <title>Error</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div>
         <textarea class="para error">
            Aww Snap!! :( Something went wrong where it was not supposed to. 
            Must be something
            <a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jack_the_Ripper">Jack</a> did!
            Please report this to the dev team.

            <!-- 
               <util:stackTrace />
            -->

         </p>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

<strike>The "Report this Error button can submit the stack trace or mail it!</strike>

Comment: having the user reporting an error is not needed in web applications.