# How to ignore logging of particular exception using log4j?

Tags: exception, log4j

I am developing an application in which I am using log4j.

In that am getting an exception **com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor**. But i don't want this particular exception to be logged.Is it possible to configure the same using log4j ??

Comment: From which jar file you import the log4j class

Comment: I am using log4j-1.2.15.jar

Comment: your answer relative to [How can I configure log4j to not print the exception stacktrace?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/348582/how-can-i-configure-log4j-to-not-print-the-exception-stacktrace)

Comment: Thank you for your response. 
What i understood from the link posted above is to ignore stacktrace for all the exceptions but i don't want to ignore all the exceptions. I want to ignore a particular exception alone. Is it possible to do that? 
 
Please correct me if i am wrong.